# "Failed to allocate data stores for 854269899 rows in section 0. Consider using fewer rows"

Tags: ios, uitableview, datepicker

i have a form in my application with datepicker as input view for one textfield.

code executes properly in simulator ,but in device it crashes with following error message

"Failed to allocate data stores for 854269899 rows in section 0. Consider using fewer rows"

My code for picker is as below

```
 if(self.fromTxtField == textField||self.toTxtField==textField)
{
    textField.inputAccessoryView = self.keyboardToolbar;
    self. datePicker  = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
    self. datePicker .datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;
    [self. datePicker  addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    textField.inputView =self. datePicker ;
}
```

Comment: Why is half of your question in all caps?

Comment: PLEASE EDIT YOUR QUESTION TO NOT USE ALL CAPS.

Comment: ya changed it to lower case

Comment: You are returning a WRONG parameter at "numberOfRowsInSection"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Before Picker View.

```
[self.fromTxtField resignFirstResponder];
[self.ToTxtField resignFirstResponder];
```

`you must also Log the message where you set the title for the pickerView.`

Comment: i have solved the issue,i had to initialise count=0 initially in(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component

function and tat resolved my bug

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue come from method `func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int)`

Consider to decrease the number of rows returned. Try with this to begin:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return 1000
}
```

And increase limit if you need it